# Refresh Page when Comment is Added

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Currently anytime I add a comment. It adds the comment to the database but freezes the buttons that I have so they do not work. Although if I refresh the page they work again. Is there a way to get the page to refresh after a comment is added. Currently the following is the code that I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>
            Untitled Document
        </title>

        <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
            SELECT P.Account, P.Image, P.Image_ID, C.Remarks, C.Users, C.Accounts, C.Date_Time
            FROM PictureDB AS P
            INNER JOIN CommentsDB AS C
            ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
            ORDER BY P.Image_ID
        </cfquery>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">

        </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  var images = {
                    <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Image_ID">
                        "#qTest.Image_ID#": {
                            "image": "#qTest.Image#",
                            "remarks": [
                            <cfoutput>
                                "#qTest.Users#, #qTest.Date_Time# <br> #qTest.Remarks# <br> </br>",
                            </cfoutput>
                            ]
                        },
                    </cfoutput>
                };
                  $("button").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var id = $(this).data("id");
                    var src = images[id].image;
                    var desc = images[id].remarks.toString();

                    $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
                    $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <cflayout name="myAccordionLayout" type="accordion" width="600px">

            <cflayoutarea title="Bill Analysis" align="left">
                        <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Account">
                    <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">
                        #qTest.Account#

                    </button>

                </cfoutput> 

                    <cfform name="InsertComments" id="InsertComments">
            <fieldset>
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">


            <textarea name="Remarks" cols="55" rows="4" label="Tour Description"
                                    required="yes" validateat="OnSubmit" message="Please enter your comment here" 
                                    enabled="no">
                        </textarea>
            <input type="text" name="Image_ID" message="Please enter Account Here." 
                                 validateat="onSubmit" required="yes" id="Image_ID" size="10"
                                 maxlength="60">
                        </input>
        <input type="submit" name="insertComments" value="Insert Comments" id="submit">
                        </input>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </fieldset>
    </cfform>
        <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>

                    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
                        INSERT INTO CommentsDB (Remarks, Image_ID, Date_Time )
                        VALUES
                        (<cfqueryparam value="#form.Remarks#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">

                        , <cfqueryparam value="#form.Image_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

                        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">

                        )
                    </cfquery>

            </cfif>


                <img id="theImage" class="hide">
        <div id="theDescription" class="hide">
        </div>
            </cflayoutarea>
            <cflayoutarea title="Operations Analysis">
        Test
            </cflayoutarea>
        </cflayout>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't you posted this code before?

Why not just do a `<cflocation>` after you execute your query back to the page? This way a user wont refresh and re submit the form and it also solves your refreshing problem.

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>
      <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
            INSERT INTO CommentsDB (Remarks, Image_ID, Date_Time )
            VALUES
                 (
                    <cfqueryparam value="#form.Remarks#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">
                    ,<cfqueryparam value="#form.Image_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                    ,<cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
                 )
      </cfquery>
      <cflocation url="URL OF PAGE" addToken="false" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Would that be directly after  </cfquery> or before it?

Comment: After it. If you do it before it it would not execute the query. I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: I would personally do an AJAX submit in JQuery and then on success use `location.reload();` to refresh the page.

Comment: @volumeone, why would you add all that unnecessary complication to something as simple as a form submission?

Comment: If you are going to do `location.reload()`, it makes no sense to submit the form via AJAX. Either submit the form the 'normal' way, or if submitted via AJAX, add some kind of event handler to refresh what parts of the page need refreshing.

Comment: Because the feedback is immediate. He can submit the form via AJAX, wait for the successful JSON response from CF, tell the user their comment has been added (on success), and then finally do a refresh if that's what he wants to do. He was saying something buttons not working unless he refreshed. Maybe I misunderstood.